# anomaly regarding floating point arithmetic in c , on subtracting a number from itself

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Consider the following code snippet:

```
float f = 0.01 ;
printf("%f\n",f - 0.01);
if (f - 0.01 == 0)
{
   printf("%f\n",f - 0.01);    
}
```

When I run this code, for the second line I get the output `-0.000000`, and the if condition does not execute .

What is the reason for the `-0.000000`?

I remember from a digital logic class I took in college that this arises due to internal representation using one's complement. Please correct me if I'm wrong and please suggest fixes and how to avoid this in the future .

I'm using clang to compile my code , if it matters.

Comment: `0.01` can not be exactly represented in binary floating point.

Comment: `float` values are not stored as 1's complement. Read here: http://floating-point-gui.de/ for everything you need to know about floating point values.

Comment: but how does it become -0.0 ? i was under the impression that zero can never be signed

Comment: @superuser47: Try printing it with `%.20f`

Comment: In floating point representation: `10000000000000000000000000000000` is `-0` because that's what the [floating point standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers) says.

Comment: @superuser47: Zero *can* be signed in commonly used floating point representations. Here, it's probably actually a very small non-zero value, caused by rounding errors when converting `double` to `float` and back.

Comment: If I would get a cent every time a floating point question like this comes up....

Comment: @MikeSeymour If it were really `-0.0`, I expect that the conversion routines would output `0.000000`.  As you say, it's probably a small negative number.  (I would guess something in the range `[-1e45,-1e320)`, give or take a couple of powers of ten.  But anything negative larger than `-0.0000005` will display `-0.000000` with `%f`.)

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, there are currently 103 pages of 50-question per page under `[floating-point]`. Even if you had one cent per each question, you would have yourself only around 50 bucks ;) Now if I had a million dollars for every time a floating point question like this comes up...

Comment: OP doesn't read a C FAQ. OP posts question about weird floating point behavior. OP gets multiple comments containing a link to Goldberg's  "What every programmer should know...". Question gets closed as duplicate. Now, I haven't seen that happen before.

Comment: @Shahbaz 50 bucks? better than nothing, I say :)

Comment: @Shahbaz `float` values can be stored as 1's complement, at least as far as the standard is concerned.  (Having said that, I've never heard of an implementation that doesn't use signed magnitude.  And for modern implementations, a base which is a power of 2, either 2, 8 or 16.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, of course, the standard doesn't specify any layout for the implementation whatsoever. But as you say yourself, no implementation uses 1's complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.01` is a `double` not a `float` (You probably have warnings about this when you compile your code.)

So, you're basically converting your "0.01" backwards and forwards between floats and doubles, which is what's causing your discrepancies.

So decide if you want to use floats (e.g `0.01f`) or doubles, and stick with one version throughout.

However, as other answers have pointed out, you'll never get an "exact" value when doing floating point arithmetic - it just doesn't work that way.

For reference, both of these versions will give the answer you're expecting

```
float f = 0.01f ;
printf("%f\n",f - 0.01f);
if (f - 0.01f == 0)
{
   printf("%f\n",f - 0.01f);    
}
```

or

```
double f = 0.01 ;
printf("%f\n",f - 0.01);
if (f - 0.01 == 0)
{
   printf("%f\n",f - 0.01);    
}
```

both print

```
0.000000
0.000000
```

Comment: so how do i use such numbers in comparisons ?

Comment: Actually, you will get an exact answer here, _if_ everything is `float`.  While the value of `0.01F` is _not_ 0.01, it should be the same everywhere.

Comment: @superuser47 By knowing what you're doing:-).  Machine floating point is not real arithmetic, and it obeys different laws.  (It is not, for example, associative.)  If you're going to use machine floating point, you have to know them, and evaluate your calculations according to its rules, and not those of real numbers.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html is the classical reference for starting.

Comment: @superuser47, if you read the link I left you in the comments, you will learn how to _use such numbers in comparisons_.

Comment: @superuser47 I've added two examples, one using all `float`s and one using all `double`s - both give the answer you're probably expecting.  So the moral of the story is don't mix float and double if you're expecting "exact" results (and even then, you're better off comparing against a smallest expected value instead of using `==`)

Comment: It would be interesting if he'd output using `"%.17g"`, rather than `"%f"`, as well.  At least he'd clearly see what is going on.

Comment: @JamesKanze I just tried - you get -2.2351741811588166e-010 for his original version (so yes, a very small negative number - or the difference between a float of 0.01f and a double of 0.01)

Comment: @benjymous Exact.  And not really such a small value, when you think about it.

Answer (score 4):

You're running into two problems:

- `0.01` can't be represented exactly as a binary floating-point value
- `f` has type `float` while `0.01` has type `double`

Your calculation requires a conversion from `double` to `float` and back which (apparently) isn't giving exactly the same value that it started with.

You might be able to fix this specific example by sticking to a single type (`float` or `double`) for all values; but you'll still have problems if you want to compare the results of more complicated calculations for exact equality.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, `0.01` can't be represented correctly in binary floating number. This can be understand by an example: `10/3` is giving the result `3.333333333333333.....`., i.e it cant be represented correctly in decimal. Similar case with `0.01`. Every floating point decimal number can't be represented correctly in binary floating point equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You have two double 0.01 - one is converted to a float. Due to loss of precision double(float(0.01)) != double(0.01)

Even without the obvious loss of precision you might get into trouble using double(s) only. A compiler might keep one as an extended double in a register and fetch the other from memory (stored as double)

Comment: It's possible, but in this case, all of the values are the immediate results of a floating point literal, and from a QoI point of view, I would expect the compiler to generate the target precision, and nothing else.  (If he'd gotten them by executing `1.0 / 10.0`, on the other hand, all bets are off, and things like `double d1 = 1.0, d2 = 1.0; d1 /= 10.0; d2 /= 10.0; if ( d1 != d2 )` are likely to have unexpected results.  Depending on the architecture, and the compiler options.

Comment: @JamesKanze In C99 and C11, under FLT_EVAL_METHOD > 0, floating-point literals may have a value that is not representable in their type. (“1 — evaluate operations **and constants** of type float and double to the range and precision of the double type …” C99 5.2.4.2.2:8). See also the results for recent GCC versions compiling with `-std=c99` of the program at http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/24/More-on-FLT_EVAL_METHOD_2 , especially `r4` evaluating to 0.